# Using Servlets and Jsp to develop a full fludged Java web Application

Tags: java, architecture

I see the projects in my new office are using servlets and jsps ,i worked on spring ,struts,hibernate and  i know how good they are ,but is it ok using servlets and jsps for a smaller web application.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with servlets and JSPs for certain problem spaces.

For small 1-off applications, where there there is significant customization, but little need to separate business logic, I can definitely see a use.

Just look to see if there is an opportunity for these small 1-off applications can be generalized, and created in a more abstracted way...

Comment: There is a lot of Buisnness logic

Comment: Then you probably want to investigate something that more formally separates your display logic (JSP) from your business logic.  Struts, Spring MVC, and the various other frameworks are really designed to help you accomplish this.  Bare servlets tend to get into trouble because it is too easy to mix controller, display, and business logic.  Eventually it tends to make a tangled mess.

Comment: Thank you,I suggested Spring MVC ,but because much of the project is already completed .they are analysing how feasible it will be.